# Конвертирую jre в ехе. Ошибка compiled by a more recent version of the Java

Tags: java

Пробую конвертировать jre в exe. Использую Launch4j. Возникает ошибка

> jni error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.
> В MIN JRE version указываю 1.4.0 В логах ошибка has been compiled by a
> more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0),
> this version of the Java Runtime.

Что у меня не так установлено?

Answer (score 0):

Видимо не был установлен  jdk. Установил